# Como atribuir uma variável do JavaScript num elemento value do HTML usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho esse código, que está pegando o evento de `click`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.js-editEstoque').on("click", function(){
    var descricao = $(this).attr('data-name-Estoque');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id-Estoque');
    $('.js-atribuicao-name').append(descricao);
    
  });  
});
```

Esse é meu HTML:

```html
<pre>
   <input type="text" name="editNameDescription" id='editNameDescription' value="" class="form-control input uppercase js-atribuicao-name" maxlength="40" required>
   <input type="hidden" name="idEstoque" value="" class="js-atribuicao-id">
</pre>
```

Quero colocar as duas variáveis acima dentro de cada elemento `value` do HTML, acredito ser algo simples mas estou com dificuldade.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa. Ao invés disso, leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour] para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site e assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: Duplicada: [Como Atribuir uma variável js num elemento value do HTML usando jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/524617/3774)

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma

```js
$('.js-atribuicao-id').val(id);
$('.js-atribuicao-name').val(descricao);
```

Conforme documentação: https://api.jquery.com/val/