# Como Atribuir uma variável js num elemento value do HTML usando jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho esse código que está pegando o evento de clico

```js
$(function(){
  $('.js-editEstoque').on("click", function(){
    var descricao = $(this).attr('data-name-Estoque');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id-Estoque');
    $('.js-atribuicao-name').append(descricao);
  });  
});
```

esse é meu html

```html
<input type="text" name="editNameDescription" id='editNameDescription' value="" class="form-control input uppercase js-atribuicao-name" maxlength="40" required>
<input type="hidden" name="idEstoque" value="" class="js-atribuicao-id">
```

quero colocar as duas variáveis acima dentro de cada elemento value do HTML, é algo simples mas estou com dificuldades :/

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa. Ao invés disso, leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour] para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site e assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: Duplicada: [Como Atribuir uma variável js num elemento value do HTML usando jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/524616/3774)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você tem de usar o metodo `val()`. Quando vaziu ex: `.val()` ele retorna o value, quando preenchido ele troca o value do element para o que meter dentro dos parenteses `.val('ola')`

```js
$(function(){
  $('.js-editEstoque').on("click", function(){
    var descricao = $(this).attr('data-name-Estoque');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id-Estoque');

    $('.js-atribuicao-id').val(id);
    $('.js-atribuicao-name').val(descricao);
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1<input type="text" name="editNameDescription" id='editNameDescription' value="" class="form-control input uppercase js-atribuicao-name" maxlength="40" required>


2<input type="text" name="idEstoque" value="" class="js-atribuicao-id">
```

Comment: porquê o down vote?